# How to use Apache Arrow to write files in Parquet format on Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, parquet, apache-arrow-cpp

I'm trying to write Parquet files on Windows using C++.
I followed the instructions I found [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/docs/source/developers/cpp/windows.rst) and chose the "Using conda-forge for build dependencies" and "Building using Visual Studio (MSVC) Solution Files" approaches.

In contrast to the article on the page mentioned before, my calls to cmake look like this:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ^
        -DARROW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF ^
        -DARROW_PARQUET=ON ^
        -DARROW_BUILD_SHARED=OFF ^
        -DARROW_BUILD_STATIC=ON ^
        -DARROW_DEPENDENCY_SOURCE=AUTO
cmake --build . --config Release
```

I want to use Parquet/Arrow as a static library, so I set `-DARROW_BUILD_SHARED=OFF` and `-DARROW_BUILD_STATIC=ON`.
In the "build" folder created after running cmake, I built the Parquet and Arrow INSTALL projects (*build\src\parquet\INSTALL.vxcproj*, *build\src\arrow\INSTALL.vxcproj*) with Visual Studio 2019. As a result, a folder structure was created under *C:\Program Files\arrow\lib* including **arrow_static.lib** and **parquet_static.lib**.
Under *C:\Program Files\arrow\include\arrow* respectively *\parquet* all related header files can be found.

I then set up a new C++ project (Release Build | x64) in Visual Studio referencing the previously build static libs and including directories.
In the project settings under "C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions" I added `PARQUET_STATIC` and `ARROW_STATIC`.
For a first test, I use the "reader_writer" example from the [apache arrow GitHub repo](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/examples/parquet/parquet_arrow/reader_writer.cc):

Now, if I build the reader_writer example, I receive multiple linking errors (LNK2001) like the following example:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char const * __cdecl apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException::what(void)const " (?what@TTransportException@transport@thrift@apache@@UEBAPEBDXZ)  ReaderWriterDemo    D:\..\ReaderWriterDemo\parquet_static.lib(column_writer.obj)
```

All errors have in common that they refer to as "thrift" at some point.
I was under the impression that when using "conda-forge for build dependencies" (see first link above), that all required dependencies would be available/somehow integrated into the solutions built by CMake?!

When running "cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64" I can see the following in the log output though:

```
-- Checking for module 'thrift'
-- Found thrift, version 0.15.0
-- Found Thrift: D:/Programs/Miniconda3/envs/arrow-dev/Library/lib/thriftmd.lib (found suitable version "0.15.0", minimum required is "0.11.0")
```

My attempts to build the thrift library separately by using the resources found [here](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/windows.html) weren't successful; information regarding Windows seems to be incomplete/outdated.

I assume that it should be possible to set up the Arrow/Parquet libs only by using resources from https://github.com/apache/arrow/.

Perhaps some of you have already gone through the same process and can give me a hint as to where else I may have missed something.